# Print out just filename from bash array

Tags: arrays, bash

I have an array and loop printing out the filename+extension, but i just want to print the filename. How can I do that?

```
tffilearray=(`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.json"`)
for filepath in "${tffilearray[@]}"; do
    echo $filepath
done
```

Comment: Btw.: I suggest to remove first line and replace `for filepath in "${tffilearray[@]}"; do` with `for filepath in *.json; do`.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
for filepath in "${tffilearray[@]}"; do  basename $filepath .json; done
```

Comment: Please mark the question as duplicate since your answer is already mentioned in the proposed duplcate.

Answer (score 0):

As Cyrus pointed out, using a shell wildcard is cleaner than `find` (since you don't need to search multiple directories or apply a complex search rule); also, you can apply the shell pattern rule (from the duplicate question) to the entire array at once:

```
tffilearray=(*.json)    # Get all the *full* filenames
tffilearray=("${tffilearray[@]%.*}")    # Trim off the extensions
```

[I'm marking this Community Wiki to avoid points on a mostly-duplicate question.]